# functions giving me garbage

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sum

I’ve created an array to get the sum, biggest number, and smallest number from all the numbers in an array. When I use a cout statement to print out the numbers I’m given garbage. Can anyone help me understand what went wrong and what to do

I previously asked a question on the same code asking about why my array wouldn’t print but I’ve fixed that problem so now the arrays are printing but after adding more functions to analyze the array and get info from it the outputs from the functions are garbage. Here’s what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int Ro = 4; 
const int Co = 5;



void fillArray(int myArray[Ro][Co]);
void printArray(int myArray[Ro][Co]);
void doubleArray(int myArray[Ro][Co]);
int max(int myArray[Ro][Co]);
int min(int myArray[Ro][Co]);
int sum(int myArray[Ro][Co]);



int main() {
 srand(time(NULL));
  int myArray[Ro][Co];
  int sum, max, min;
  
  
cout << "\n\n\n";
  fillArray(myArray);
  printArray(myArray);
  
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "The largest number is : " << max;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "The smallest number is : " << min;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "The sum is : " << sum;
  
  
  cout << "\n\n";
  doubleArray(myArray);
  printArray(myArray);
  return 0;
}


void fillArray(int myArray[Ro][Co]){
  
for (int r = 0; r <= Ro; r++)
{
  for(int c = 0; c <= Co; c++){

  myArray[r][c] = (rand()%100);
    }
  }
}
void printArray(int myArray[Ro][Co]){
  for(int r = 0; r < Ro; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c < Co; c++){
      cout << myArray[r][c] << " "; 
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
}
void doubleArray(int myArray[Ro][Co]){
  for(int r = 0; r < Ro; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c < Co; c++){
      myArray[r][c] = myArray[r][c]*2;
    }
  }
}
int max(int myArray[Ro][Co])
{
  int max = myArray[0][0];
  for(int r = 0; r < Ro; r++)
    {
    for(int c = 0; c < Co; c++)
      {
        if(myArray[r][c] > max){
          max = myArray[r][c];
        }
      }
   }
  return max;
}
int min(int myArray[Ro][Co])
{
 int min = myArray[0][0];
  for(int r = 0; r < Ro; r++)
    {
    for(int c = 0; c < Co; c++)
      {
        if(myArray[r][c] < min){
          min = myArray[r][c];
        }
      }
   } 
  return min;
}
int sum(int myArray[Ro][Co])
{
  int sum = 0;
  for(int r = 0; r < Ro; r++)
    {
    for(int c = 0; c < Co; c++)
      {
        sum += myArray[r][c];
        }
      }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: you run off the end of the array here `for (int r = 0; r <= Ro; r++)`, you mean `<` not `<=`, same error repeated everwhere

Comment: @Azphyxia There are no calls of the functions min and max.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually using uninitialized variables rather than calling the functions of the same name. You have both functions and variables named `max`, `min` and `sum`. The variables have garbage values because they weren't initialized.

If you intend to call the function rather than use the variable, then you need to place parentheses after the function name with the needed arguments inside parentheses, like this:

```cpp
  max = max(myArray);
  min = min(myArray);
  sum = sum(myArray);
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "The largest number is : " << max;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "The smallest number is : " << min;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "The sum is : " << sum;
```

Comment: *'variables are shadowing the function declarations with the same name'* -- Shadowing never came in unwanted ways within OP's code

Comment: I have the variables new names by putting “get” in front of all of them ex: getmax, getmin, getsum. As well as adding calls for the functions themselves inside the body but it’s still not working.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep You're right. I forgot that C++ can have multiple things named the same. I have removed the sentence about shadowing from my answer.

Comment: Thank you, adding the function to the assignment of the variables helped.

Answer (score 1):

as i pointed out in a comment , you run off the end of every array all the time

```
for (int r = 0; r <= Ro; r++)
{
  for(int c = 0; c <= Co; c++){

  myArray[r][c] = (rand()%100);
    }
  }
}
```

should be

```
for (int r = 0; r < Ro; r++)
{
  for(int c = 0; c < Co; c++){

  myArray[r][c] = (rand()%100);
    }
  }
}
```